# Analysing an RCT with many zeros in outcome

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution, hazard, clinical-trials, random-allocation

I have a RCT to analyse – my outcome is number of days late (20 days late being the maximum). The majority of people are not late, so there are a lot of zeros in the dataset. I’m expecting that the treatment will both reduce the number of people who are late (thus, increase the number of zeros) and will reduce the number of days among those who are late.

My question is, what is the correct way to analyse this in order to capture the change in the number of days late among those who wind up being late? I could just ignore the zeros, but this would bias my estimate.

I’m also not sure what kind of model best suits the data (I have covariates to include in the analysis). OLS would be simpler (and from what I understand, pretty robust to misspecification in the context of an RCT), however, my data is on an interval scale and bounded and there is also over dispersion, so I was thinking of using negative binomial regression, however, I am also wondering if a hazard model would be more appropriate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time-to-event (e.g. Cox regression) makes some sense (it is in some sense a "how long until something" outcome), but it is problematic to deal with 0 days (logically time-to-event requires a strictly positive outcome plus the discreteness of the number of days scale is non-ideal).

For that reason, count outcomes make a lot of sense (easier to deal with the zeros) and you can also deal with cases where you do not observe the time (and only know that it is, say, >20 days; not buildt in by default in most software, but essentially just requires 1-F(x) as the likelihood contribution).  Out of the count outcomes negative binomial regression makes a lot of sense (accounting for differences in risk across patients) and can deal with covariates. There is also a zero-inflated version.